# How to check if email exist in data base yii2 basic

Tags: email, yii2

How  I can check if an email exist in the data base in yii2 basic , I connect the database with the framework,but need help ,how to check this (its needed for the forgot password (form) )

Comment: show the related model  ..

Comment: in rules you can check email for check existance

Answer (score 1):

assuming the the email you are looking for is in $email_to_check and the ActiveRecord is YourClass should be somethings like this

```
$model = YourClass::find()->where(['email'=> $email_to_check]);

If (isset($model)) {
 // then your email exists
}
```

could be

```
$modelUser = User::find()->where(['email'=> $email_to_check]);

If (isset($modelUser)) {
 // then the User with your email exists
}
```

Comment: @ros  .. tell me if there are problem with my answer .. please